# Windows 10: Login screen won't appear when click on lock screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, recovery

Today when I started my PC, first it got stuck on the motherboard logo screen. Then, after force reboot, windows tried to diagnose and repair itself. When finished the lock/welcome screen appeared, but when I click on it or press any key it kind of sweep up like it is going to show the login screen but "reload" and stays in the welcome screen.

I have a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17PZ9EUrehLszgzNqjXy3eI0SbgrwB3uc/view?usp=sharing) of the behavior.

I have tried booting from an USB drive with the windows tool and using the commands `sfc /SCANNOW` and `chkdsk: /f /r` from the CMD but didn't solve anything (chkdsk showed that there isn't any corrupted files).

Any idea what could it be?

Comment: Go to the Media Creation Link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)  Down load the Windows 10 ISO and make a bootable USB Key. Boot with that and see if you can repair Windows.

Comment: I have tried it too. It starts diagnosing but after a few seconds it says it can't repair windows.

Comment: Is this problem showing when you load Safe Mode?

Comment: trying safe mode now

Comment: it only shows a black screen and the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Today when I started my PC, first it got stuck on the motherboard logo
> screen. Then, after force reboot, windows tried to diagnose and repair
> itself

**Background:** A repair from the Windows 10 ISO created from the Media Creation Link did NOT work.

**Solution:**

Start with a bootable USB Key (Windows works) so that you can start a command prompt.

Back up Documents and Email (and anything else you wish).

Now do a fresh install of Windows and recover your data when it is running.

**Proviso:**  You should make sure the main disk is not broken. Run hardware tests on the disk.

Comment: There is any way to run those tests from the computer I'm trying to repair?
Edit: I'm able to access windows from the command prompt. There is something I can do from there? create a backup or try to repair it from there.

Comment: See if the manufacturer has a bootable USB version of Hardware Diagnostics. That is the only way at this point.  If not, gamble on installing Windows.

Comment: I selected the CMD option. My user appeared and I selected it. It asked for the password and opened the command prompt. The problem is that it shows the unit X:/. Can't access my files from there and can't cd to C:/

Comment: I'm going to look for the MSI hardware diagnostics software, see if I can do anything with it. Thanks for the help John.

Comment: If you cannot access the files, the operating system is severely compromised. Hopefully you have some other backups as it appears all you can do is reinstall windows

Comment: I took this approach: First I have run MX Linux Live from an USB drive and copied the whole HD into an external HD. It took some time but now I have a complete backup. After that I executed a recovery keeping the personal documents. Aaaand problem "solved"! Now I have to install all the programs and configure everything, but at least I didn't lose anything...